# $_GET variable functions differently in two controllers for no obvious reason (Yii)

Tags: php, arrays, yii, frameworks, get

I have CMS (built in house) using the Yii 1.x framework. It uses the Bootstrap TbGridView widget for showing records in a tabular format with pagination.

These GridView views have dropdown menus that allow the admin user to do some filtering on the data. The model attributes are set as illustrated below using the $_GET variable.

```
$model->setAttributes($_GET[get_class($model)]);
```

So a $_GET string as follows generates the following:

myapp.local/myapp/myuser/admin/ajax/myuser-grid/Myuser%5Bfirstname%5D//Myuser%5Bsurname%5D//Myuser%5Busername%5D//Myuser%5Byear_id%5D/11/Myuser_page/2

This generates the following $_GET array:

```
Array ( 
   [ajax] => myuser-grid 
   [Myuser] => 
      Array ( [firstname] => [surname] => [username] => [year_id] => 11 ) 
   [Myuser_page] => 2 )
```

As you can see the 'Myuser' key contains an array (with firstname, surname etc..)

Now for some reason on another module within our CMS which works 'seemingly' in the same manner the $_GET variable isn't generating in the same way. For instance the following url string returns the $_GET variable differently for some unknown reason.

myapp.local/myapp/shop/products/ajax/myuser-grid/Myuser%5Bfirstname%5D//Myuser%5Bsurname%5D//Myuser%5Busername%5D//Myuser%5Byear_id%5D/11/Myuser_page/2

This generates the following $_GET array

```
Array ( 
   [ajax] => myuser-grid 
   [Myuser[firstname]] => [Myuser[surname]] => [Myuser[username]] => [Myuser[year_id]] => 11
   [Myuser_page] => 2 )
```

I am expecting to look exactly the same as the other array above (with Myuser being in an array format) for some reason it doesn't do the same.

Can anyone suggest why the $_GET variable would appear differently, the only difference is the one comes from my myuser controller and the other the shopProducts controller.

Can anyone give me a clue as to why this would be happening?? P.S I cannot see any logic that is manually manipulating the $_GET variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to me like an url rewrites issue. You should inspect .htaccess files and urlManager in yii.